# OpenCart. Запрос БД. Вывод переменных

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, opencart

Здравствуйте. Прошу идеи, предложения или еще что-то по реализации данного вопроса.

Допустим, что есть подобная схема, которую нужно будет реализовать на странице товары(`cms OpenCart`). В каждой карточке товара (на общей странице товаров) будет мини калькулятор, в который будет подгружаться через `SQL` запрос по средствам `PHP` корректные цены для каждого товара.

После они будут обрабатываться `JavaScript` кодом для калькуляции.

От сюда вопросы:

Kак построить логику запроса, который будет брать цены от каждого товара находясь на общей странице товаров?

Как загрузить переменные через `echo`, если стандартный `HTML` редактор (в него будет записываться таблица для калькулятора) комментирует объявление `PHP` кода?

Спасибо всем ответившим, буду рад любым предложениям, ссылкам на статьи, примерам и тд.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если честно, не до конца понятен вопрос: товары только данной категории или все товары, цены будете брать основные или, как и положено, будете учитывать скидки, акции и т.д.. Ну и использовать надо возможности ОС, а вариантов здесь много, даже если не писать собственный модуль/дополнение. Контроллер Категории (/catalog/controller/product/category.php) передает массив данных о продуктах в шаблон формирования страницы категории (/catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/category.tpl), единственное, что изначально массив данных о продуктах формируется из модели продуктов (/catalog/model/catalog/product.php) с учетом сортировки, фильтрации, пагинации и т.д..
Как я это вижу, один из вариантов ("наколенный" и не самый правильный):
Открываем файл контроллера, который отвечает за Категорию /catalog/controller/product/category.php и добавляем

```
 $data['calculator'] = array();
$filter_calculator = array(
                'filter_category_id' => $category_id,
                'filter_filter'      => '',
                'sort'               => 'p.sort_order',
                'order'              => 'ASC',
                'start'              => '0',
                'limit'              => '9999'
            );
$calculators = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($filter_calculator);

foreach ($calculators as $calculator) {

                if ($this->customer->isLogged() || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                    $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($calculator['price'], $calculator['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
                } else {
                    $price = false;
                }
                if ((float)$calculator['special']) {
                    $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($calculator['special'], $calculator['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
                } else {
                    $special = false;
                }
                if ($this->config->get('config_tax')) {
                    $tax = $this->currency->format((float)$calculator['special'] ? $calculator['special'] : $calculator['price'], $this->session->data['currency']);
                } else {
                    $tax = false;
                }

                $data['calculators'][] = array(
                    'product_id'  => $calculator['product_id'],
                    'name'        => $calculator['name'],
                    'price'       => $price,
                    'special'     => $special,
                    'tax'         => $tax,
                    'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&product_id=' . $calculator['product_id'] . $url)
                );
            }
```

Тогда в шаблоне (/catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/category.tpl) можно будет сделать так:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($calculators as $calculator) { ?>
<tr id=calc_<?php echo $calculator['product_id']; ?>>
<td id=calcname_<?php echo $calculator['product_id']; ?>><?php echo $calculator['name']; ?></td>
<td id=calcprice_<?php echo $calculator['product_id']; ?>><?php echo $calculator['price']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

ID строк и ячеек будет уникальным и зависимым от id товара, можно будет js обрабатывать как будет удобно.
Вообще, в ОС очень читабельный и простой код, и соответствие MVC архитектуре, попробуйте разобраться. [Руководство разработчика](https://docs.ocstore.com/index.php?title=%D0%A0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)